# How to copy a data inside {{}} from another website for a variable for use in my site?

Tags: javascript, php, html, copy, clone

Firstly, the site is: http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/megasena/

And the content that I want copy is the series: "081015232534".

Before render, the series is generated by the code:

`{{resultado.concurso}}`

And after render, the series is showed like this:

`<ul class="numbers megasena" id="ulDezenas"><li>08</li><li>10</li><li>15</li><li>23</li><li>25</li><li>34</li></ul>`

So, I'd copy the numeric output of {{resultado.concurso}}
 for a variable for I use this number in my website.

How can I do it?

PS1: I thought to do this through some function in php or js.

Something that:

```
url    = "http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/megasena/";
target = {{resultado.concurso}};
myVar  = functionCopy(url, target);
```

I just don't know if such function exist.

PS2: Question edited!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This is a open ended question that can have multiple solutions.

Comment: Simple: Explain-me the solution more simple. Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to do web scrapping, I would advise to research about the topic first. (https://www.scrapehero.com/a-beginners-guide-to-web-scraping-part-1-the-basics/)

Comment: You likely want to research "web scraping", but if you're content with just displaying the node on your website you can always just use an [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp).

Comment: I thought in something in php or javascript...

Comment: Actually, I didn't thought in copy the entire frame, but yes in just store the content of "resultado.concurso" in a variable.

Comment: When the page loads, look at the ajax requests it is doing...

Answer (score 1):

This is called "scraping". There are many considerations so there is no one answer we can just post on a StackOverflow question, but it's a topic you can research. There are also some legal considerations you'll want to keep in mind: does the site you're scraping allow scraping?

Finally, if you haven't already, double check that the service doesn't already have an API for providing the data you need. Sometimes even sites you don't expect to have an API have a small one you can use to get basic data.